# Clear three text elements to the right of small icon without wrapping

Tags: html, css

I want to float three text items right of a left-floated icon that is smaller than the text items, without the text items wrapping.

```
div {
    width:30%;
}
div i {
    margin-right:0.75em; 
    padding:0.5em;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    clear:both;
    background:rgb(255,143,69);
}
h3 {
    margin-bottom:0.75em;
}
p {
    margin-bottom:2.75em; 
    overflow:auto;
}
a {
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#ff8f45; 
}
```

As you can see from --

http://jsfiddle.net/zu3k814d/7/

-- I've cleared the heading and paragraph with clear on the icon and overflow for the paragraph but the link/anchor below stays stuck left. I would like it to line up with the heading and paragraph above it. I could give it a left margin until it clears the image and lines up with the stuff above, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way.

Comment: So, you want to display the anchor tag with the icon, not below it on the left, but on the right, when heading and the paragraph are cleared.. right?

Comment: He wants the `a` tag to be lined up to the right of the image like the `h3` and `p` tags are, but without using margin-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to reorganize your html to make it easier to float both items.

Here is the working code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kamsiyo/zu3k814d/46/) `--`

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Didn't think of wrapping everything up like that in another div.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `float`, use [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

i {
  margin-right: 0.75em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clear: both;
  background: rgb(255, 143, 69);
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 2.75em;
  overflow: auto;
}

a {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #ff8f45;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div>
    <i class="material-icons">fingerprint</i>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <a href="">Learn more...</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very helpful, Joseph. Thanks. I'm very new to flex stuff, so I'll stay a bit floaty for now. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I understood from your question:

So, you want to display the anchor tag with the icon, not below it on the left, but on the right, when heading and the paragraph are cleared, right?

Here is what you can do to do that:

add `display:inline-block;` in the css for `a`.

Like the following:

```
a {
    font-size:0.9em;
    color:#ff8f45; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And then your result will be something like:

Here is the link to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zu3k814d/27/) that I updated.

---

**EDIT**: You can display the anchor tag to the right by adding the following two attributes in you css for `a` tag:

```
a{
  font-size:0.9em;
  color:#ff8f45; 
  white-space: nowrap;
  float:right;
}
```

---

I hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your time. But no, something more along the lines of this -- http://jsfiddle.net/dy8e0542/12/ -- where I've forked the original fiddle with a margin on the anchor to show what I'm looking for. That seems hacky though, the margin.

Comment: got your point now, so you want to basically display the anchor tag in the right side of the column, there is better way to do that without giving margins, because the code with the margins can have different results in different sized windows.